# Array comparison

Tags: arrays, perl

I have two arrays and I'm using `list::compare` module. The first array is

```
@log, "$each_line[3]|$each_line[14]"
```

The second array is

```
@log2 "$each_line2[3]|$each_line2[14]|$each_line2[37]"
```

Is there any way to make these arrays match and print this?

```
"$each_line[3]|$each_line[14]|$each_line2[37]"
```

Comment: What does List::Compare have to do with your question.  And are those pipe-separated strings supposed to be single example elements in the arrays?  Are the arrays sorted?  Is there always a match in @log2 to an element in @log1?

Comment: It would really help if you could show complete sample input (code that assigns stuff to @log and @log2) and your expected output.

Comment: Is `@each_line` another array, and `@log` and `@log2` containing references to its elements?

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't say how the matching is done, the example seems to imlpy it's basically an "or" of corresponding array elements.

As such

```
my @array1 = split(/\|/, $string1);
my @array2 = split(/\|/, $string2);
my $length1 = scalar(@array1);
my $length2 = scalar(@array2);
my @new = ();
my $max = $length1 < $length2 ? $length2 : $length1;
for (my $index = 0; $index < $max; $index++) {
    push @new, $index < $length1 ? $array1[$index] : $array2[$index];
}
```